# Add an index for each Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel file, each worksheet is only identified with its name,

I need to add a new property Index for each worksheet

Is it possible to identify worksheets with their index depending on their position?

[property pop-up for the worksheet object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTq2.png)

Comment: Worksheets("nameOfYourSheet").Index returns the index of the named worksheet. Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, but more specifically i need to add a new property (index) for each worksheet which displays the value of its index, for example the first worksheet would have a property index = 1, the second would have a property index=2 etc...

Comment: What do you mean by property? It already is a property and it behaves exactly like you described.

Comment: Wait you mean for it to show up in the window from your screenshot? What do you need that for? I also don't believe that's possible. If you tell.us what you are planning to do, I'm sure someone can come up with better solution.

Comment: Yeah, I want to add the index property to the window (pop-up) shown in the screenshot attached ( worksheet object properties window). This Excel file would be an input for reqtify (requirement management tool), only the first worksheet should be taken into account (all the other worksheets should be ignored except the first one), hence each worksheet should have a property Index which defines the worksheet index , this would help reqtify to filter worksheets depending on their index , not depending on their name ( the name of the first worksheet could change and filtering with name won't help)

Comment: And the only way to retrieve an index of a worksheet for that tool you are describing is for the index to show up in the properties window? I'm not familiar with the tool but I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: Well, I understand that it is difficult to implement,

Comment: Converting this excel file to an xml file only the worksheet name is parsed as shown below: <Workbook>
  <Worksheet name="Electrical rating">
    <Row num="2">
      <Cell col="2" label="B2">Test</Cell>
      <Cell col="2" label="B2">Test</Cell>
      <Cell col="3" label="C2">Test</Cell>
      <Cell col="4" label="D2">Components</Cell>
      <Cell col="5" label="E2">Components</Cell>
   Do you have an idea on how the attribute index could be added and displayed in the converted xml file? Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, just pass it the index, starting at 1: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(index)`

For example: Given the first sheet in your workbook is named "Sheet1", then
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` reference the same sheet.

The Index property for worksheets already exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.index. The index is automatically updated, if you rearrange your sheets. You can test it with this code:

```
Sub printSheetInfo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        Debug.Print ("sheet with index " + CStr(sh.Index) + " --> " + sh.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

It should output something like this

```
sheet with index 1 --> Foo
sheet with index 2 --> Baz
sheet with index 3 --> Bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually I need to add a new property (index) for each worksheet which displays the value of its index, for example the first worksheet would have a property index = 1, the second would have a property index=2 etc...

Answer (score 1):

First sheet in your sheet tab will have the index 1. Be carefull, if the sheet in the first position is hidden then it has also number one so first visible sheet has number 2.
To find out if the sheet is visible, use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Visible which has state xlSheetHidden or xlSheetVisible.
First sheet is: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) which has name ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name. You can also ask for the index if you know the name of the sheet then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yourname").Index

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually I need to add a new property (index) for each worksheet which displays the value of its index, for example the first worksheet would have a property index = 1, the second would have a property index=2 etc...